# upgrading systemd from backpor 215-230

Tags: systemd

Hi i have been tasked with little resarch so apart of testing via VM i also ask:
I need to upgrade systemd 215 to 230 on live server on which services are running, its per say streaming server. One of the new component need to utilize systemd 230 and cant work with 215.

its pretty simple per guide
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363016/how-to-upgrade-my-systemd-to-latest-version

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install systemd
```

But - how it will affect running service? Would i need to stop them all or restart? I simply tired to upgrade on clean system with no problem nor even reboot needed - verified with systemd --version

I plan now to install some simple web service or something and check the behavior but other than than, i would also like to acquire some theory background regarding this from community, so please :)

I assume it its not a problem and at worst, the services needs to be restarted, maybe reboot would be optimal even tho its live server, it can be done as maintenance. Would be great if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your base systems is `jessie`, it should be a safe upgrade, and [systemd can be safely restarted with `systemctl daemon-reexec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419374/can-i-restart-systemd-without-rebooting). The syntax should be largely compatible, but check the systemd changelog for breaking changes that may affect you, and testing the upgrade in a VM first is still a good idea.